# Configuring IEEE 1588 PTPV2 with STM32 and ksz8463

Tags: stm32, ptp, stm32h743

I want to set up ptp (precision time protocol) now and HSR protocol in future. So I have a STM32H743ZIT6 and a KSZ8463FRL switch.
The switch has 3 port. According to datasheet port 1 and port 2 can be used as TC (Transparent Clock: P2P/E2E) and port 3 can be used as OC (Ordinary Clock: Master/Slave). I'm confused. Which port should connect to my mcu? Which port should be connect to GMC (Grand Master Clock)? My board is slave for another master now but can my board be used as Master too?
I connect port 3 to mcu and port 1 and 2 is free.
I haven't enough information. Please help me or introduce useful references. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary Clock Ports are uplink facing so Port3 should be connected to GM. This this configuration, the MCU board is slave for GM and can be connected to port 1 or 2.
To use the board as Master, the MCU has to be connected to port 3(Port 3 always connects to Master). The CPU can sync to a GPS and act as GM this way.
The 1588v2 support on STM32H743 may be buggy... as per STM32 forums.

Comment: Please read following user guid:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/ksz8463ml_eval_kit_user_guide_0.11.pdf
It says mcu must be connect to port 3:
"The KSZ8463ML is a highly integrated 2-port 10/100Base-T/TX/FX managed Ethernet switch with a third port for interfacing to a host processor."